# "Uncaught Invalid Chrome Web Store item URL" while inline installation of chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a Chrome extension and also published it to tester group on Chrome Webstore. When I am trying to load (add) the extension from my site, getting error as

> Uncaught Invalid Chrome Web Store item URL.

On method `Installer.prototype.install = function(url, onSuccess, onFailure)` in webstore javascript file (provide by chrome to install extension on browser).

I have done to install extension by inline installation which is approached by Chrome.

I have verified the "url" on inline installation by browser address space which is properly getting the extension location on chrome web store.

I am not able to find the problem, please help me to come out of this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Make sure that your URL is of the form `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID`. The Chrome Web Store recently started to advertise URLs of the form `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/*title*/itemID`, which are not accepted for inline installation.

For example, for [Google Mail Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-mail-checker/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff), the URL should be `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff`, not `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-mail-checker/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff`.

Comment: This may only be a functional solution for those extensions that are published universally. Google seems to think these links are invalid for extensions restricted to testing accounts.